# NPM API for listing all dependencies of a component

Tags: javascript, node.js

If you visit https://registry.npmjs.org/randomstring you can get information about the package `randomstring` like the version, etc. But this does not give you the list of its dependencies.

I know there are CLI commands and modules to list the dependencies of a package, but is there an API? Preferably, you get all the deps, including deps of the deps.

Just to clarify, I want the API to return the deps of the deps too. Not just the deps of the original package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 'version' field you have all the versions deployed on npm. If you take a look at version 1.1.5 (the latest) there's the dependency field you are looking for (array-uniq as dependency, and mocha as devdependency).

Comment: Yes it does, but it only gives you its dependencies. I want the deps of the deps too.

Comment: You could get the first level dependencies and their version of "randomstring", then make other http calls for each dependency you've got. So you get https://registry.npmjs.org/randomstring, then you read the dependencies of the latest version (1.1.5) and read its dependency (array-uniq version 1.0.2), then make a get call to https://registry.npmjs.org/array-uniq/1.0.2  and get its dependencies (it doesn't have any of them). If you want, you can get the devdependencies as well. Be aware that for big packages you may need to perform a lot of requests.